# Unable to retrieve optional params

Tags: angular

As far as I can tell from the Angular docs, I should be able to get a route's options parameters from `route.paramMap`, but when I try logging out the params from it, I get back an empty object.

I'm creating a login page, and want to pass the referring URL to it. For example:

```
http://localhost:3000/login;referrer=%2F
```

In my header component, I setup the following:

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => console.log(params));
}
```

But I just get back `{}`. Am I using the wrong method?

As requested, my route configs:

My root route config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LandingComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
];
```

And then a second module with my login page:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedOutGuard]
    },
];
```

Comment: that doesnt look as a route param though, and it strongly depends on the routing configuration.

Comment: Show how you defined your routes

Comment: @Jota.Toledo As the URL was generated by Angular, I can assuredly say it's structured properly. To be clear, its an optional param, not a part of the URL (https://angular.io/guide/router#optional-route-parameters). I'll add my route definitions, but it won't show anything useful.

Answer (score -1):

Try using like this:

```
this.route
   .queryParams //<------
   .subscribe(params => {
      this.page = params['page'];
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's also an empty object.